# Apagar y reiniciar sistema operativo con javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs, linux

Como podría mandar a **reiniciar** y tambien **apagar** la pc con `javascript` en el frontend o con `NodeJS` en el backend?, utilizo **Linux como SO**. Estuve investigando y leí algo sobre poner como hipervinculo un archivo `.lnk` que realizaría la acción, pero no tengo idea de como conformar el archivo `.lnk`.

Gracias de antemano...

Comment: Gracias joni es lo que buscaba

Comment: Perfecto, si te sirvió y pudiste ponerlo en marcha, puedes marcar la pregunta como solucionada de manera que pueda ser de ayuda a otros usuarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se haría uso de exec.

Para apagar el PC:

```
// shutdown.js

// Require child_process
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

// Create shutdown function
function shutdown(callback){
    exec('sudo /sbin/shutdown now', function(error, stdout, stderr){ callback(stdout); });
}

// Reboot computer
shutdown(function(output){
    console.log(output);
});
```

Para reiniciar:

```
// reboot.js

// Require child_process
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

// Create shutdown function
function shutdown(callback){
    exec('sudo /sbin/shutdown -r now', function(error, stdout, stderr){ callback(stdout); });
}

// Reboot computer
shutdown(function(output){
    console.log(output);
});
```

> Fuente:
>   https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/411/how-to-shutdown-and-reboot-linux-with-node-js

Para evitar que se te soliciten las credenciales, deberás dar permisos al usuario de node.js para ejecutar dicha tarea:

Creamos un fichero en `/etc/sudoers.d/` que le añadiremos el siguiente contenido:

```
USUARIODENODEJS ALL=/sbin/shutdown
USUARIODENODEJS ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown
```

Recuerda modificar `USUARIODENODEJS` por el usuario correspondiente.

Saludos,

Comment: amigo lo estoy probando pero no funciona , lo probé haciendo un update de los paquetes del sistema y lo hace , pero el apagado y reinicio no, porque sera

Comment: tendra que ver con ejecutarse con permisos de administrador o algo?

Comment: Prueba a modificar el `exec` incluyendo `sudo`, te lo actualizo en mi respuesta.

Comment: en el apagar, al utilizar `sudo` cuando lo ejecutas en la terminal te pide password,, no lo puse porque imagino que si me apagaría la pc, pero el problema es que ese comando se ejecutara cuando den click en apagar en una vista de la web, y en ese caso no tendré como pasarle el password

Comment: Voy a actualizar la respuesta, dame un par de minutos

Comment: el lió es que necesito que cuando se ejecute ya sea con permisos de administrador en ambos casos en el reiniciar y en el apagar

Comment: Te comprendí. Actualicé la respuesta con la manera de dar los permisos.

Comment: y como sabria cual es el USUARIONODE , el mismo usuario de la pc??

Comment: No deberías ejecutarlo como ROOT, sería un grave problema de seguridad. Puedes ejecutar: `ps aux | grep node` para obtener procesos que concuerden con node, una vez ahí identificará que usuario está ejecutando el proceso.

Comment: gracias, ya lo probé con el mismo usuario de la pc y funciono, muchísimas gracias amigo